# Seeking USA electric transmission powerlines as shapefiles?

Tags: data, united-states

Does anyone have a good source for USA electric transmission powerlines as shapefiles?

I have some old (1993) data from the US National Renewable Energy Laboratory ([NREL](http://www.nrel.gov/)) and Cubewerx' WMS ([Cubewerx](http://www.cubewerx.com/) are a spatial data provider); neither of which are very accurate.

Pipeline shapefiles other than the 10 year old NPMS data would also be helpful.

Comment: to clarify the 1993 NREL data is here: http://www.mapcruzin.com/renewable-energy-us-electric-transmission-shapefiles.htm Looking for something more accurate and recent.

Comment: I bet users of the GTC-EPRI siting model know where to get this data. http://www.gatrans.com/PlanningConstruction/EPRI-GTCSitingModel/index.htm  You might try contacting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NERC & FERC are going to be your best bets in getting correct data.

http://www.ferc.gov/

http://www.nerc.com

Not only will you most likely have to pay for the data, but I don't believe you can have access without certifications and clearances (national security threats, etc). Both of the resources above should help you find what you need to do to get the most recent/correct data and the resources to go to in regard to both transmission and pipeline data.

Answer (score 3):

This is not generally free data. Two providers I've used are [Platts](http://www.platts.com/Products/gisdata) and [Ventyx](http://www.ventyx.com/index.asp). Costs are roughly the same (not cheap!) and I've found the Ventyx stuff to be more detailed though Platts has been better on occasion.

Comment: right on Swingley, we are probably going to be having to purchase the data. Thanks for the Platts and Ventyx links, we were thinking of purchasing from RexTag http://www.rextagstrategies.com/ but those might be better.